# How to overload @ in python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I want to overload the operator `@` in python for a class I have written. I know how to do operator overloading in general (i.e. by defining `__add__` and `__radd__` to overload `+`) but I could not find a way to overload `@`.

Why I know, that `@` can be overloaded: for numpy arrays, `A@B` gives the matrix product of `A` and `B`, while `A*B` gives the Hadamard (element-wise) product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods you need to overload are the `__matmul__` and `__rmatmul__` methods. E.g. if you want to add the inner product to lists:

```
class Vector(list):
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return sum(x * y for x, y in zip(self, other))

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        return self.__matmul__(other)
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this information is in the section on [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in the language reference.