# How did numpy add the @ operator?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How did they do it? Can I also add my own new operators to Python 3? I searched on google but I did not find any information on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overload @ in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511972/how-to-overload-in-python)

Comment: See [PEP 465](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't add your own. The numpy team cooperated with the core Python team to add `@` to the core language, It's in the core Python docs (for example, in the operator precedence table), although core Python doesn't *use* it for anything in the standard CPython distribution. The core distribution nevertheless recognizes the operator symbol, and generates an appropriate `BINARY_MATRIX_MULTIPLY` opcode for it:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a @ b
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_MATRIX_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 5):

Answering your second question,

> Can I also add my own new operators to Python 3?

A similar question with some very interesting answers can be found here, [Python: defining my own operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators)

Recently in PyCon US 2022, Sebastiaan Zeeff delivered a talk showing how to implement a new operator. He warns that the implementation is purely educational though. However, it turns out you actually can implement a new operator yourself! Locally, of course :). You can find his talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYKGZunmF50&ab_channel=PyConUS), and his code repository [here](https://github.com/SebastiaanZ/pypethon). And if you think your operator could enhance Python Language, why not [propose a PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0001/) for it?

Comment: What a great talk, thanks!